# number of possible integer roots are

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $P(x)$ is a cubic polynomial with integer coefficients that has at least one integer roots.If $P(2)=5,P(4)=3,$ Then number of possible integer positive roots are

what i try

Let $P(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ and $a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{Z}$

$P(2)=8a+4b+2c+d=5\cdots \cdots (1)$

$P(4)=64a+16b+4c+d=3\cdots \cdot (2)$

$\Longrightarrow 56a+12b+2c=-2$

$\Longrightarrow 28a+6b+c=-1$

How do i solve it Help me please

Comment: Hint: write $P(x)=(x-r)Q(x)$ and plug in $x=2$ and $x=4$; this will tell you that $2-r$ divides $5$, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it have three integer roots? (Let alone, three positive integer roots.) Call them $r<s<t$, and $P(x)=\pm(x-r)(x-s)(x-t)$. (No larger leading coefficient because the leading coefficient divides both $3$ and $5$.) We have:
$$5=\pm(2-r)(2-s)(2-t)$$
$$3=\pm(4-r)(4-s)(4-t)$$
where in each equation, the three factors are distinct. The three factors in the second equations are each larger (by $2$) than the corresponding factor in the first equation. If the factors of the first equation were $-5$, $-1$, and $1$, then the factors in the second equation would be $-3$, $1$, and $3$, which multiply to $-9$. If the factors of the first equation were $-1$, $1$, and $5$, then the factors in the second equation would be $1$, $3$, and $7$, which multiply to $21$. So it's just not possible.

---

Could it have exactly two integer roots? Assume no doubled roots. Call them $r<s$. Then $P(x)=(x-r)(x-s)(ax+b)$ where $a,b$ are integers and $|a|>1$. Since $P(2)=5$ and $P(4)=3$, you have 
$$5=(2-r)(2-s)(2a+b)$$
$$3=(4-r)(4-s)(4a+b)$$
In each case, one factor is $\pm$ a prime ($5$ or $3$) and the other two factors must be $\pm1$. Now, $(4a+b)-(2a+b)=2a$, and $|a|>1$. It follows that $(4a+b)$ and $(2a+b)$ cannot both be $\pm1$.

If $(2a+b)=\pm5$, then $2-r=1$ and $2-s=-1$, so $r=1$ and $s=3$. This leaves us with $2a+b=-5$ and $4a+b=1$, which leads to $a=3$ and $b=-11$. So we may have $$P(x)=(x-1)(x-3)(3x-11)$$
We don't need to investigate the other case where $(4a+b)=\pm3$, because all we are trying to do is see if it is possible for $P$ to have exactly two integer roots, and we've established by example that it is. Moreover, it is possible to have two positive integer roots, as this example does.

(Another example is $(7-x)(x-3)^2$, if we allow doubled roots.)

---

Is it possible that $P$ has exactly one positive integer root? Assume it is not repeated. Call that one root $r$. Then $P(x)=(x-r)Q(x)$ where $Q$ is quadratic with no positive integer roots. Then
$$5=(2-r)Q(2)$$
$$3=(4-r)Q(4)$$
So $2-r$ divides $5$, with $r$ positive. This implies $r\in\{1,3,7\}$.

$r=1$ would imply $Q(2)=5$ and $Q(4)=1$. There are quadratics that meet these conditions without having integer roots. Such as $Q(x)=2x^2-14x+25$. So we need not look further.

---

Is it possible that $P$ has no positive integer roots? Then the integer root we assume is non-positive. That means $P(x)=(x+r)Q(x)$ with $r\geq0$. So: 
$$5=(2+r)Q(2)$$
$$3=(4+r)Q(4)$$
So $2+r$ divides $5$, with $r$ nonnegative. This implies $r=3$. But then considering the second equation, $7$ would have to divide into $4$. So it's not possible.

---

In summary:

There is always *at least* one positive integer root.

It is possible $P$ has *exactly one* positive integer root. For example $P(x)=(x-1)(2x^2-14x+25)$.

And it is possible $P$ has *exactly two* positive integer roots. For example $P(x)=(x-1)(x-3)(3x-11)$ or $P(x)=(7-x)(x-3)^2$.

It is not possible for $P$ to have three positive integer roots.

Answer (score 1):

Since $P(2)=5$, let $P(x)=(x-2)Q(x)+5$
We have $3=P(4)=2Q(4)+5, Q(4)=-1$
So we could se $Q(x)=(x-4)R(x)-1$
Now we have $P(x)=(x-2)(x-4)R(x)-x+7$
If the positive integer root of P is t, so we have
$0=(t-2)(t-4)Q(t)-t+7$, or $t-7=(t-2)(t-4)Q(t)$ 
Since t is positive integer,$|t-7|\lt |t-2|$, t must be 7 and Q(7)=0.
So P(x) only has one positive integer root which is 7.

Comment: $P(x)=(x-1)(x-3)(3x-11)$ has two positive integer roots (neither of which are $7$) and meets the requirements that $P(2)=5$ and $P(4)=3$.

Comment: You're right. We could only get that t could not be more than 7 since t-7 could be negative value.

Comment: And if 0<t<7, t could not be 2 and 4 (otherwise the rightside is 0 but leftside not). So we need to check t=1,3,5.
And t=5 is invalid since -2=3*Q(t) requires 3|2.
t=1 means -6=3*Q(1) so that Q(1)=-2, it is possible.
t=3 means -4=-Q(3).

Comment: Q(1)=-2 provides solution P(x)=(x-2)(x-4)(a(x-1)-2)-x+7  
Q(3)=4 provides solution P(x)=(x-2)(x-4)(a(x-3)+4)-x+7  
Q(7)=0 provides solution P(x)=a(x-2)(x-4)(x-7)-x+7  
The first two equal requires a(x-1)-2=a(x-3)+4, or a=3  
    The last two equal requires a(x-3)+4=a(x-7) or a=-1  
The first equals to the last requires a(x-1)+2=a(x-7), no such a available

Comment: a=3 provides solution (x-3)(x-1)(3x-11)
a=-1 provides solution -(x-7)(x-3)^2

Comment: I'm not entirely following, but how about the solution $(x-1)(2x^2-14x+25)$? There are actually many solutions of this form.

Comment: Yes, there're many form with only a single positive integer root. But only two special cases with multiple positive integer roots